# Flutter Consumer<Generic>?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to generate a Consumer widget but that can work for two different Providers depending on a parameter

```
 class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({
    Key? key,

    required this.dataProvider,
  }) : super(key: key);


  final IceCreamProvider dataProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Consumer<dataProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Container();
            },),
}
```

Of course, this code is not working, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The generic should be the `TYPE` of the variable, so in your case you have to use `IceCreamProvider` and not the variable name `dataProvider`

**Updated with the addition of HeaderWrapper**

Since you want to pass the provider, you must go up one level and give your `ChangeNotifierProvider` (assuming you are using that) the correct instance you want to use

```
class HeaderWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const HeaderWrapper({
    Key? key,
    required this.dataProvider,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final IceCreamProvider dataProvider;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => dataProvider,
      child: Header(),
    );
  }
}
```

then inside the `Header`, just use the Consumer as written before (you can even skip the field dataProvider inside since it will be not used)

```
class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<IceCreamProvider>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Generic handling: Edit after user comment**

You can't simply pass a Type as a parameter and set into the bracket as a Generic, however you can add a generic to your class

```
class Header<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<T>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      return Container();
    });
  }
}
```

**usage:**
`Header<IceCreamProvider>()`

Comment: I understand, but that's exactly my question is there a way to "send" that TYPE as a parameter? or defined it as an abstract class to be able to setup the consumer as 2 possible TYPEs?

Comment: it is not possible to send the type as parameter, but you can include that as generic in your class, editing with the solution

Comment: That's a good idea, however if we included it as generic in the class to create the Consumer widget then, the "value" inside the builder wouldn't know any of the methods inside my ChangeNotifier provider class.

Comment: Going through the dart documentation I found this: 

We must specify the type of the model that we want to access. In this case, we want CartModel, so we write Consumer<CartModel>. If you don’t specify the generic (<CartModel>), the provider package won’t be able to help you. provider is based on types, and without the type, it doesn’t know what you want.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#consumer